# comboBoxWillDismiss event not fired when changing NSComboBox

Tags: objective-c, events, nscombobox

I have an NSComboBox defined in Interface Builder, and the `-(void)comboBoxWillDismiss:(NSNotification *)notification` function in my .m file.
However, when changing the content of the `NSComboBox` (internal cells, not data source), the `comboBoxWillDismiss` does not get fired.
What did I forget to do?

Comment: Try to set your .m file's class as the delegate of your ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

It worked as per comment recommendation: [myCombo setDelegate:self].